# Machine learning in Clojure

Tags: clojure, machine-learning, numeric, symbolic-math

We have theano and numpy in Python to do symbolic and numeric computations, optimising our Machine Learning computations (eg: Matrix multiplications and GPU usage). What are the relevant tools in Clojure to do Machine learning (or at least things like matrix multiplications)?

Answer (score 6):

An important library / tool for mathematical operations, statistics and more in Clojure is [incanter](http://incanter.org/). There is also [clatrix](https://github.com/tel/clatrix) wrapping jBlas for matrix operations.

With regard to machine learning in general, there are at least two libraries interfacing / wrapping [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/) which includes [MLlib](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-guide.html) for machine learning: there is [sparking](https://github.com/gorillalabs/sparkling) and [flambo](https://github.com/yieldbot/flambo). [clj-ml](https://github.com/antoniogarrote/clj-ml) is basically a wrapper around [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) and some additions. Finally, [clojure-opennlp](https://github.com/dakrone/clojure-opennlp) is a wrapper around [opennlp](https://opennlp.apache.org/), an NLP toolkit comparable to NLTK in Python.

This [list of ML tools](https://github.com/josephmisiti/awesome-machine-learning#clojure) provides quite some more links.

Answer (score 3):

For the matrix/vector side there's [`core.matrix`](https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix) which is a plug-able library with an implementation at 
[`vectorz-clj`](https://github.com/mikera/vectorz-clj) that is being actively developed, and other high perf libs exist. Usage from the readme:

```
(def M (matrix [[1 2] [3 4]]))
(def v (matrix [1 2]))
(mul M v)
=> #<Matrix22 [[1.0,4.0],[3.0,8.0]]>
```

A 'mentor' to the project mentioned [on an answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312905/gpu-programming-on-clojure) that GPU was a target, but no mention of it in the docs.

What kind of specific functionality do you need as your question is a bit broad? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Basically something that allows numeric operations to be done efficiently (as if I am using Octave / Matlab). core.matrix is definitely something i am looking for. Thanks!